# Linear Algebra What does it mean to Span $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> What is the difference between vectors being a basis for
> $\mathbb{R}^3$ and vectors being a basis for a subspace of
> $\mathbb{R}^3$?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question... do you know what a basis is?  Do you know what $\Bbb R^3$ is?  Do you know what a subspace is?  Have you seen any examples of subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$?  I would have thought this to be self-explanatory.

Comment: Are the definitions of basis, span, subspace and $\mathbb{R}^3$ clear to you? If not, where is the breakdown? I think once that is cleared up you will be able to answer your own question.

Comment: If you have a collection of vectors who are a basis for $\Bbb R^3$ that means that every element of $\Bbb R^3$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of those basis vectors.  If you have a collection of vectors who are a basis for $V$ that means that every element of $V$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of those basis vectors.  If $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ then that means that each element of $V$ is an element of $\Bbb R^3$ but not necessarily the other way around... so some elements of $\Bbb R^3$ might not be expressible as a linear combination of your basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few tins of paints in a few colours. They are your basic colours. Mixing them in various proportion you may be able to obtain a large collection of colours, call them generated colours (span)

Another person with different set of tins (basic colours) may be able to generate only a limited set of colours than you (and nothing that you can't generate). Then his basic colours give you a subspace, yours the whole space.

If you study about HTML pages and colours in a web page they are obtained using R, B, G (red, blue and green). If you are banned from using Red (due to some dislike for communism!) then the colour space you get is only a subspace of all possible colours.

Comment: +1 for a unique explanation of span I've never heard before.

Comment: very helpful thank you

Answer (score 0):

A basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a set of three vectors with which you can express any other vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (using linear combinations).

A basis for a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a set of vectors with which you can express any other vector in the subspace (using linear combinations).

Answer (score 0):

A set of vectors, $\{v_1, v_2, V_3, \cdot\cdot\cdot\}$ "SPANS" a vector space, V, if and only if every vector, v, in V can be written as a linear combination of vectors in the set.  That is, $v= a_1v_1+ a_2v_2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$.

In particular, if the two columns of this matrix, <1, -2, 3> and <-2, 7, -9>, for any <x, y, z> there exist numbers, a, and b, such that a<1, -2, 3>+ b<-2, 7, -9>= <a- 2b, -2a+ 7b, 3a- 9b>= <x, y, z>.  So a- 2b= x, -2a- 7b= y, 3a- 9b= z.  Can we solve those THREE equations for the TWO unknowns, a and b?
If we multiply the first equation, a- 2b= x, by 2 to get 2a- 4b= 2x and add to the second equation we eliminate a and get -11b= 2x+ y so b= -(2x+ y)/11.  If instead we multiply the firt equation by -3, to get -3a+ 6b= -3x, and add to 3a- 9b= z, -3b=   -3x+ z so b= (3x- z)/3.

So those two vectors CANNOT span all or $R^3$,  it spans the subspace of vectors <x, y, z> such that -(x+ y)/11= (3x- z)/3.   The -3(x+ y)= 11(3x- z). -3x- 3y= 33x- 11z.  3y= -36x+ 11z so we can say this subspace of all <3x, 3y, 3z>= <3x, -36x+ 11z, z>= <3x, -36x, 0>+ <0, 11z, z>= <3, -36, 0>x+ <0, 11, 1>z.

So these two vector span a two dimensional space.

(Actually, we could have avoided all this calculation by using the fact that two vectors can span a one dimensioal space (if they are "dependent") or a two dimensional space (if they are "independent") but two vectors CANNOT span a three dimensional vector space such as $R^3$.)